# how to use reactJS component inside backbone and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, backbone.js, reactjs, components

I have backbone application and angularJS application, in the meantime, I am using reactJS to create component library. Now the goal is to use reactJS component directly inside backbone and angularJS.

I know there is ngReact plugin in angularJS, but the question is, can I use my reactJS component directly inside backbone and angularJS application without changing any reactJS component code?

Also, both angularjs and backbone is using grunt to run and minimized, when I using reactJS component inside backbone and angularjs, is the minimization still working for reactJS simultaneously?

Hope to hear your advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Backbone, it sounds like you would just want to directly render your components within your views. [This](http://www.thomasboyt.com/2013/12/17/using-reactjs-as-a-backbone-view.html) is a good article about how to do that.

In AngularJS, the best way to do this would probably be directly rending your component from within a directive. [Here](http://blog.500tech.com/using-reactjs-with-angularjs/) is an in-depth article about how to achieve that.